# Kotlin with few libraries causes cannot fit into single dex file

Tags: kotlin, overflow, dex

Getting this error was kind of normal after adding a lot of libraries in java.But now thanks to kotlin I only added two simple libraries and I get :

```
Error: null, Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file (# methods: 65881 > 65536)
```

Here's the gradle:

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha4'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha4'
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//maps
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
//Permission Library
implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
```

I know,i can fix this adding multidex to the project.But I want to know where are 65536 methods!!I don't have any method written myself yet,it's just a hello world app.Is anybody having the same issue?Deleting the test libraries,how much would it help?

Comment: What is inside of your `./libs` folder?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to use [dexcount-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/KeepSafe/dexcount-gradle-plugin) to find out which dependency add most methods. For the next step, I will try to write dependencies tree in order to find out whether there are some duplicate dependencies (got transitively). This can be done with pure gradle: `./gradlew moduleName:dependencies`. If you see some duplicate dependencies, you could exclude them easily in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Duplicate dependencies are very common and are usually resolved automatically by Gradle, are they not?

Comment: I presume gradle does that with duplicate dependencies with the same versions. My point vas that using `dependencies` command, he at least identify ones that do not have the same version and maybe update his dependencies accordingly.

Comment: Thank you I tried the plugin and the maps library seems to be having a lot of methods.Even though they seperated the libraries into single ones.Like this one is only place.It makes no sense!Why so many methods?

Comment: Sorry, mate, I can't help you any further. I have never used that library :(. Isn't there any alternative for your project?